# how to use VB.NET to connect to sql server with user 'sa' and restore a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am new to VB.NET, and needed some help to make a connection to sql server.

I instralled sql server 2008 r2 express with instance name "sqlexpress", and passowrd "sql123".

I need to create a connection to this server instance, with user 'sa', and restore my .bak database file. 
After this I thought to create a new user with name and password 'inituser', only for this database, running a T-SQL query with VB.NET.

This is my initial function:

```
Private Sub DBConnect()
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim q1 As SqlCommand
    Dim q2 As SqlCommand

    myConn = New SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;User Id=sa;Password=sqlexpress1;")
    ' restore the databse .bak file
    q1 = myConn.CreateCommand
    q1.CommandText = "RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 FROM DISK = '" + _DBFilePath + "'"
    ' create new user for EasyFarmacy Database
    q2 = myConn.CreateCommand
    q2.CommandText = "CREATE LOGIN inituser WITH PASSWORD = 'inituser' USE EasyFarmacy GO CREATE USER inituser FROM login inituser GO"

    Try
        myConn.Open()
        q1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        q2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Database connection error!  + '" + ex.Message + "'")
    End Try
    myConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing this through the sql server management studio ?

Comment: It would be easier but this function with be executed on button click. I need it this way..

Comment: Maybe write some stored procedures and call these from your code?

Answer (score 0):

Of course a command like that needs to be executed with [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
myCmd.CommandText = "CREATE LOGIN inituser WITH PASSWORD = 'inituser'"
myConn.Open()
myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Now, for the Restore part I suggest to use a reference to the SMO Libraries deployed with your installation of Sql Server. You could find the assemblies required in GAC

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended
```

and then you could use the Restore class to perform your operation. The steps required are numerous and they depend on your context. So I give your a link to the [MSDN page about this Restore class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx) where you could find a full example of a restore operation executed programmatically

Comment: Is is possible to make a database restore, from VB.NET?

Comment: You could use the T-SQL command for that like you have used the one above to create the user

Comment: Sure, but you need to know some things, like data files logical and physical names etc. Search MSDN for 'restore database'.

Comment: A side note. The SMO libraries offers complete functionality for Backup and Restore

Comment: I only need to restore the database the first time. When I executed the application it shows an error at the '@' symbol in conection string. "Unexpected token"

Comment: It seems legit but I cannot test here. So the better choice is to create a backup of a dummy database, make some changes (just modify a couple of records) and then try the restore operation. Check if it worked restoring the previous records state.

Comment: . When I executed the application it shows an error at the '@' symbol in conection string. "Unexpected token"

Comment: Is VB.NET. It doesn't require that character. Remove it

Answer (score 0):

you gave to execute your command:

```
Private Sub DBConnect()
Dim myConn As SqlConnection
Dim myCmd As SqlCommand

myConn = New SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;User Id=sa;Password=sql123;")
myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
myCmd.CommandText = "CREATE LOGIN inituser WITH PASSWORD = 'inituser'"
myConn.Open()
myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()



myConn.Close()
```

End Sub